# Cannot add panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

The code I have, creates a set buttons but are vertically aligned

[image]

Now what I wanna do is add a JLabel to this panel but when I create an new JPanel, I get an error when I run it, but code doesn't give me any conflicts. And I would like to rearrange the buttons in a flowlayout  if possible.

my full code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public final class CharSearch extends Box {
    int i = 0;
    int error = 0;
    static JPanel panel;
    String original = "Dinosaur";
    String secret = new String(new char[original.length()]).replace('\0', '-');

    public CharSearch() {

        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++) {
            String buttonText = new Character(i).toString();
            JButton button = getButton(buttonText);
            add(button);
        }
        JLabel label = new JLabel(secret);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
    }

    public JButton getButton(final String text) {
        final JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (original.indexOf(text) != -1) {
                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                            "Your word does contain" + text);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "There is no" + text);
                }
                // If you want to do something with the button:
                button.setText("Clicked"); // (can access button because it's
                                            // marked as final)
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setContentPane(new CharSearch());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                new CharSearch();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the error I get when I run it

[image: Error]
`Exception` is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.informatica.com.CharSearch$2.run(CharSearch.java:50)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of how you want your UI to look? Merely saying that you want a `FlowLayout` isn't going to help us understand your requirement :)

Comment: Like all the buttons must align on the top and the label must be under it but centered

Answer (score 4):

You are adding an undefined JPanel object to your JFrame, resulting in a `NullPointerException`, as is noted in the [`Container#add(Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) documentation.

```
frame.add(panel);
```

You must instantiate `panel` before adding it to your JFrame's content pane container.

Comment: Okay what do you mean define panel

Comment: Oops, I meant instantiate.  `panel = new JPanel()`

Answer (score 3):

For the `NullPointerException` it's because of this line:

```
frame.add(panel);
```

While you've created a global variable `panel` you are not instantiating it before adding it to the `frame`